# Why is this looping through each id in mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't understand why this provides a form option tab of each id in the array and not just one of them. Can someone explain? aka: Why is the `$id` variable not a static number. Thanks!

```
<form action="form_connect.php" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <select name="id" id="">
  <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>";
    }        
  ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

[result that i'm confused by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMECx.png)

Comment: For learning purposes, look at the SQL query that gets stuck into `$result`. You are most likely getting more than one row from that query.

Comment: Yeah I get 3 rows from my table but was not sure how the loop shuffled through each id. I think I understand now though. I thought $id = $row['d'] would make $id into an array of numbers. Thus making it necessary for you to put <option value='id'>$id['0']</option>". But as Obsidian said below the while loop must automatically loop once for each variable in the $row array. Although I think I understand why I thought you would need a for loop (i=0, i < $row.length, i++) {$row ['i']}

Comment: the `while` loop asks `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to grab a row from `$result` until `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns nothing. So `$row` only contains one row at a time.

Comment: Ohh I get it now thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns an associative array, and considering you're calling it inside a `while` loop, you're iterating over each of the elements within that array. That is to say, apply the logic within the `while` loop to *each* of the elements in the array (individually, one at a time). Thus, each time you iterate over the array, the `$id` is set to the `id` value of the *current* element targeted by *that* iteration.

You then `echo` this out with `echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>"`, meaning that your `<select>` will be populated with *multiple* `<option>` elements, one for each element in the array.

Comment: Thanks so much for the incredibly detailed and clear answer. Much appreciated! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I thought I would need to do something like this: (i=0, i < $row.length, i++) {$id = $row. echo <option value='$id'> $id['i'] </option>

Comment: ^ That's a `for` loop. A `while` loop essentially does the same thing, under the hood. It occurs *while* the condition is `true`. A `mysqli_result` contains data, so thus is `truthy`. When you finish iterating over the data, the value becomes `falsy`, and thus the execution stops. See [*PHP type comparisons*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: THANK YOU YES. That further explanation hit the spot. _Now_ I completely understand. Tyy.

Comment: Your wording seem to indicate (to me) that you are iterating the `$row` array, while you're actually iterating the `$result`.

Comment: Yeah I thought the while array would call for the entire table at once and thus the $row variable would be the one iterating through id’s but it didn’t make sense bc if that was the case the while loop would only iterate once thus making the $row variable static. But yeah now I understand the while loop gets each row one at a time from the MySQL table that $result points to and thus iterates once for each row.